# Добавление своего модуля в PyCharm python

Tags: python, pycharm, модули

День добрый. Мой вопрос заключается в следующем, написал собственный модуль для своей же программы. Раньше работал в Sublime Text 3, там модуль встал без проблем, но тут я решил перейти на другую IDE, и тут проблема, Pycharm, не в какую не добавляет мой модуль(сторонние модули добавляются без проблем). Может кто знает, как побороть мне эту проблему. Заранее благодарю!
Конфиг, IDE определила без проблем, а вот модуль погоды...
Так же прикрепляю скрин папки.

[image]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня модули из приложения лежат в самом проекте приложения. Ну а где еще? Иначе помещаются в pip (общий или pipenv)

Comment: В первую очередь - проверить пути к каталогам, где лежит ваш файл с модулем.